# Problem in installing hortonworks sandbox

Tags: java, hadoop, virtualbox, sandbox

I am trying to install **Hortonworks Sandbox** on **VirtualBox**. Process goes on to 17% and then this error occurs. I have tried many times but still the same problem. So please anyone let me know the possible errors.[image]